# Is there a way to change the caracters of a String one by one by caracters in a tab?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, replace

My main purpose is to stockpile the caracters stocked in a tab into a `String` with the same length.

So what I've tried is to replace each caracter of a `String` I declared at the beginning by the caracter at the same position in the tab using a `for` loop and the method `replace(oldChar, newChar)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String card = "xxxx";
  char[] code = {'0', '1', '2', '3',};

  for (int i = 0; i < code.length-1; i++) {
    card.replace(card.charAt(i), code[i]);
  }
  System.out.println(card);
}
```

I expected the output of `0123`, but when I run the code, it shows the original string value (`xxxx`), as if the `for` loop was useless.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char) returns a **new String**. Old String is unchanged.

Comment: If you would like to do such thing (as you mentioned), you might want to change the type for `card` into `char[]`...and if needed return a `String` after the manipulation.

Comment: @hesseux As @Andreas pointed out, `replace` replaces everything so this code will never work.  I'd just like to point out if you used `replace` because you saw `replaceAll`, they **both** replace all occurences, just using different ways.  It is a common thing to get confused about.

Answer (score 4):

> I expected the output of 0123 but when I run the code, it shows the
>   original string which is xxxx, as if the for-loop was useless

In Java String objects are immutable. The `replace` method returns a new String object which has your required modifications.

`card = card.replace(card.charAt(i), code[i]);`

P.s. Also, your `for` loop is not covering the last element of the array. Run it for `i < code.length`.

Comment: Check my answer. Strings are not objects, they're arrays. Right? Oh, right, you forgot to put a comma right after "In Java" so that's how I misunderstood what you were saying.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `char[]` into a `String`, call the [`String​(char[] value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D)) constructor:

```
char[] code = {'0', '1', '2', '3'};
String card = new String(code);
System.out.println(card); // prints: 0123
```

---

Your code will never work, even if you fix the issue with capturing the result of calling `replace`, as described in other answers, because on first iteration `card.charAt(i)` returns an `'x'`, so `replace(card.charAt(i), code[i])` means `replace('x', '0')`, replacing **all** the X's, resulting in `card = "0000"`.
Second iteration: `card = "1111"`
Third iteration: `card = "2222"`
Fourth iteration: `card = "3333"`

If you want to *build* a string, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
char[] code = {'0', '1', '2', '3'};
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("xxxx");
for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) 
    buf.setCharAt​(i, code[i]);
String card = buf.toString();
System.out.println(card); // prints: 0123
```

*Or:*

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) 
    buf.append(code[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java Strings are immutable, meaning that you can't change them. When you call `String.replace()` it actually returns a new string, rather than modifying your old string. If you want a String with the content like what you have in your array, use the String constructor, `card = new String(code)`. Then the String will contain the data `0123`.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you do `code.length - 1`? I mean `code.length` is actually *what* you need. The *length* starts from 1 in this string: `"a"` and changes up to 2 in this string: `"ab"`.

So actually the length of `code` does not start a 0 for a single letter, it starts at 1 for a single letter. The length would be actually `code.length` ***NOT*** `code.length - 1`.

Also, as others pointed out, strings are immutable in Java. That means you can't change them. When you do `String.replace()` it returns a new string instead of the old string changed.

So this is the correct code in the `for` loop:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < code.length; i++){
  card = card.replace(card.charAt(i), code[i]);
}
```

So in this case, I changed `card` because I did not use the `replace` function by itself, I actually changed `card` into its replacement.

First of all, what I did was I changed `card` to `card.replace(card.charAt(i), code[i])`. So I still preserved the original string but changed it, not create a new string.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way, imho, is to do it in one statement using the methods provide by the String class.

Give the following:

```java
      String card = "xxxx";
      char[] code = { '0', '1', '2', '3',
      };
```

You can do this.

```java
      card = String.valueOf(code) + card.substring(code.length);
      System.out.println(card);  // prints 0123
```

The way this works is.

1. String.valueOf(code) converts the char array into a String.
2. card.substring(code.length) gets the rest of the string starting at 4 in this case.
3. Then they are concatenated together.

If you had a String instead of an array of characters, you could use it directly.

This method also preserves excess characters in card if the string is longer than the code array.

Comment: @zixuan  So?  I didn't change the string, I created a new one. Obviously you didn't check my code because it works.

Comment: @zixuan So if you think preserving the string is better then 1) why didn't you raise that issue with the other answers and 2) why did you not preserve the string yourself?